# Working with SD-card on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, audio, windows-phone-8, sd-card

I read this topic [Reading from the SD card on Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj720573%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_Step1Specifycapabilities) and try to get audio files from SD-card. But I have some problem, when is call `IEnumerable<ExternalStorageFile> rootFiles = await rootFolder.GetFilesAsync();` I get empty list. 
I think, problem in manifest with file extensions. I try write some extensions, but have no result.

```
  <FileTypeAssociation TaskID="_default" Name="MP3" NavUriFragment="fileToken=%s">
    <Logos>
      <Logo Size="small" IsRelative="true">Images/test/Route_Mapper_Logo33x33.png</Logo>
      <Logo Size="medium" IsRelative="true">Images/test/Route_Mapper_Logo69x69.png</Logo>
      <Logo Size="large" IsRelative="true">Images/test/Route_Mapper_Logo176x176.png</Logo>
    </Logos>
    <SupportedFileTypes>
                <FileType ContentType="application/mp3">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="audio/mpeg">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="audio/mpa">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="audio/mpa-robust">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="audio/mpeg3">.mp3</FileType>
                <FileType ContentType="audio/mp3">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="audio/x-mpeg-3g">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="video/mpeg">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="video/x-mpeg">.mp3</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="video/mpeg">.mpg</FileType>
      <FileType ContentType="video/mpeg">.MP4</FileType>
    </SupportedFileTypes>
  </FileTypeAssociation>
```

What could be the problem in?
Thanks for answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can't register windows phone reserved file types yourself. they will be simply ignored